# mas_updateConstraints didn't remove constraint in Masonry

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint, masonry-ios-osx

I'm using [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) in my `UITableViewCell`, the cell has two subviews, one is `contentLabel`, the other one is `imageView`.
While the `imageView` is not always present, if the cell has one image url, present it, or hide. If the `imageView` is hidden, I want to set the `contentLabel` to `cell.contentView.bottom` to another value, something is like below:

```
  [_contentLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_left);
    make.top.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom).offset(20);
    make.right.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_right).offset(-6);
    _bottomConstraint = make.bottom.equalTo(_imageView.mas_top).offset(-14);
  }];

  [_imageView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
    make.left.equalTo(_contentLabel.mas_left);
    make.bottom.equalTo(self.contentView.mas_bottom).offset(-14);
  }];

  if (tweet.imageUrl) {
    _imageView.hidden = NO;
    [_imageView sd_setImageWithURL:tweet.imageUrl placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loading"] options:0];
  } else {
    _imageView.hidden = YES;
    [_imageView sd_setImageWithURL:NULL];
  }

  if (_imageView.hidden) {
    [_contentLabel mas_updateConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
      make.bottom.equalTo(_imageView.mas_top).offset(0);
    }];
  }
```

But I always got Error msg below:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fef9cd178d0 UILabel:0x7fef9cd437e0.bottom == UIImageView:0x7fef9cd26260.top - 14>",
    "<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fef9caf5430 UILabel:0x7fef9cd437e0.bottom == UIImageView:0x7fef9cd26260.top>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<MASLayoutConstraint:0x7fef9caf5430 UILabel:0x7fef9cd437e0.bottom == UIImageView:0x7fef9cd26260.top>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

That seems `mas_updateConstraints` didn't remove the old constraint, but add a new constraint, the two conflicted each other. So how could I update the constraint value dynamically based in runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this was not your problem, but it might help others:

My problem was essentially the following:

I assigned first a height constraint to a subclass of `UIView`:

```
make.height.equalTo(label); // label is another subclass of UIView
```

Later, I tried to „update“ this constraint using:

```
make.height.equalTo(@(newHeight)); // newHeight is a CGFloat
```

This left the original constraint installed, and added a new constraint that conflicted with the 1st one.

I then changed the assignment of the 1st constraint to:

```
CGFloat labelHeight = label.frame.size.height;
make.height.equalTo(@(labelHeight));
```

**…and the conflict was gone.**

Apparently, iOS Masonry cannot update a constraint defined by a `UIView` by a constraint defined by a `NSNumber`.